# Casting IQueryable to IOrderedQueryable generically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a generic method where I take an `IQueryable<T>` and returns an `IOrderedQuerable<T>` using Linq-to-Entities.

A simple `input.OrderBy(p => p.something)` won't work since I don't know any property of `T` (and I cannot constrain this to an interface).

Casting the result to (`IOrderedQuerable<T>`) seems to work until you try do actually use it with a `.Skip()` or `.Take()`, at which point you get a runtime error.

I guess I theoretically could use reflection and see if I find an `int` or something and build an expression to use as ordering, but that seems very dirty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you need to pretend that something is ordered?

Comment: What does it mean to convert an `IQueryable<T>` to an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` when you haven't applied any sort?

Comment: `input.OrderBy(t=>0);` or some other constant may be enough to do it, but ask yourself why you're trying to produce an "Ordered" queryable that isn't actually ordered in any meaningful way.

Comment: @KirkWoll LinqToEntities will not allow Skip and Take operations on an IQueryable, and need to apply paging to my query.

Comment: @Toodleey: If you try to make an `IOrderedQueryable` without a real ordering, then how do you know you won't get results in different arbitrary orders for each page?  i.e., you might get items from page 1 again in page 3 if they happened to come back later in the list that time.  That's why that requirement is there - it only make sense to do paging operations if you have an unambigious order.

Comment: "need to apply paging to my query" - then you *need* to define an order. That's what the framework is pushing you towards.

Comment: solved by Damien_The_Unbeliever in the comments! thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
input.OrderBy(p => 0);
```

This way you'll have the items in the same order they were initially. However, this will cost extra CPU.

Comment: Why will this put items in the same order they were initially?

Comment: @mellamokb, it will not **put** items in the same order they were initially; it will not alter the initial order of the items.

Comment: So if I make a call to the database for page 5, and the database decides to send me results in a different order than it did when I requested the rows for page 4, how will this help exactly?

Comment: @mellamokb, how exactly the database **will decide to send results in a different order**?

Comment: @RePierre: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2700184/116614 for example.  There's lots of reasons, such as page rearrangement, optimization, current I/O activity, current cached data, creating/removing indexes from the table, etc.  Point is, you should never rely on the default order of rows from a database because it's undefined and there's no contract by the database vendor to guarantee a stable order.

Comment: @usr - it's always worth checking [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx): "This method performs a stable sort;". That being said, I agree with the general theme that of the comments that this is all very silly and the OP ought to be getting an ordered enumerable if that's what they actually need.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's the documentation for `Enumerable.OrderBy`. [`Queryable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264.aspx) does not and cannot promise the same.